# versioning in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, fluent-nhibernate

In my NHibernate mapping files I used:

```
<version name="Version" column="Version" />
```

to implement versioning. How do I achieve this using fnhibernate?

What should go in here?

```
public class blaMap : IAutoMappingOverride<bla>
    {
        public void Override(AutoMapping<bla> mapping)
        {
            ????
        }
    }
```

thanks.

christian

Comment: This might be it: mapping.Version(x => x.Version); but I am not too sure yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this did the job:

```
mapping.Version(x => x.Version);
```

hope this helps someone else.

Christian